# How to make polyhedron nanoparticles with spheres

Tags: modeling

I'm very new to Blender, I want to build polyhedrons filled with spheres to represent nanoparticle models. I knew there is an addon "Add Mesh: Extra Objects" that allows creating various polyhedrons. However, I can't find a way to create mashes with a fixed distance from one edge to the other edge. The results of the model I want to have looked more or less like this.[image]
Would you please help me out with that? Thank you.

Comment: Look into molecular addon script, here's a video demonstration:  https://youtu.be/7hCTTVLETCA

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial showing how to create nanoparticle using particle system: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bya5xQUiEgo&t=9s